# Aplicacion Laravel no funciona en Digital Ocean

Tags: laravel, digitalocean

Hola subi mi proyecto a Digital ocean con Ubuntu 18 y solo me llega al HOME las demas pagina me sale este mensaje :

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: En tu log de Laravel agrega que errores aparecen

Comment: Debes agregar mas detalles, este error suele ser porque no esta habilitada la re-escritura de URL o urls amigables como le digas. Como atender el tema depende de si instalaste apache o nginx

Comment: Te falta configurar las reglas de reescritura, en apache o NGINX

Comment: Manda la url del proyecto o sube una imagen...